# Posible Pair of Enantiomers

Tags: stereochemistry

> What is the number of possible enantiomers in monochlorination of 2-methybutane?

#### My approach

When $\ce{Cl2}$ is added to any alkane it prefers $3^\circ > 2^\circ > 1^\circ$. 
When it is being added to 2-methybutane, final product (major) formed will be 2-chloro-2-methybutane, which will show 0 chiral centre, hence the maximum number of enantiomers will be

$$2^n = 2^0 = 1$$

My book gave me answer $2$, but no explanation is provided.

Comment: You gave a good explanation, the book did not give any - you win! Or they meant the question differently: of all the products that could form, how many are chiral?

Comment: @Who, I was wondering what happened to your doctoral title (:D). Btw preference of chlorination is highest at tertiary carbons, that's true, but don't you think it will definitely happen even at secondary and primary centers (albeit to a lesser extent). That's why we say "major product" is the tertiary one, but minor products also form.

Comment: Which book are you taking this question from?

Comment: Chlorine is less selective then Bromine in free radical reactions(at least here).Even though tertiary radical is most stable as in the post , its product product may not be major.

Comment: Partly related: [What is the major product on chlorination of 2-methylbutane?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/26949/7951)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming monochlorination of 2-Methyl Butane ,the following products are possible as shown in the figure below.
[image]